# Uploading php Project in Bluemix

Tags: php, ibm-cloud, uploading

We have uploaded our php project build in codeignitor framework in Bluemix server, the project has been build successfully but deployed unsuccessfully. So, what shall we do to deploy the project successfully in the Bluemix server?

Comment: Could you please post logs with error? cf logs <app name> --recent would provide logs.

Comment: 2015-09-23T19:13:46.05+0530 [App/0] OUT 13:43:46 httpd | [Wed Sep 23 13:43:46.039169 2015] [core:info] [pid 44:tid 140349573535488] [client 75.126.37.74:56649] AH00128: File does not exist: /home/vcap/app/htdocs/test/info.php
2015-09-23T19:13:46.05+0530 [App/0] OUT 13:43:46 httpd | 75.126.37.74 - - [23/Sep/2015:13:43:46 +0000] "GET /test/info.php HTTP/1.1" 404 211 vcap_request_id=08034fb8-7e2a-4387-73db-7ef7ca827e49 peer_addr=75.126.37.74

Comment: `File does not exist` is telling me that you have a configuration problem with your php app. Would be difficult to debug without seeing your code.

Comment: From previous comment it seems that you application started fine but it has problems getting the resources. Please send full recent logs and try to explain/show what your application should do.